# How to draw concentric circle nested diagram ? Using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I drew the picture but I do not know how to add text inside.

I want to add the text to the circle.

```css
.shapeborder {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.outer {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 400px;
  /* You can define it by % also */
  height: 400px;
  /* You can define it by % also */
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.inner {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  /* of the container */
  width: 50%;
  /* of the container */
  height: 50%;
  /* of the container */
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer circle shapeborder">
  <div class="inner circle shapeborder">
    <div class="inner circle shapeborder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't creating an actual image be easier?

Comment: Or SVG. There are some great online SVG editors, like http://editor.method.ac/

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ht89/7Lg7d4m3/)

The idea is to place the text in a `span` for each `div`.

```
<div class="outer circle shapeborder">
  <span>Release planning</span>
  <div class="inner circle shapeborder">
    <span>Iteration planning</span>
      <div class="inner circle shapeborder">
        <span>Daily planning</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each **span** will use `position:absolute;` and the parent **div** will use `position:relative;`.

By doing that you can position the text easily.

```
div {
  position: relative;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
span:last-child {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```css
.shapeborder {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.outer {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 400px;
  /* You can define it by % also */
  height: 400px;
  /* You can define it by % also */
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.inner {
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  /* of the container */
  width: 50%;
  /* of the container */
  height: 50%;
  /* of the container */
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

span:last-child {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer circle shapeborder">
  <span>Release planning</span>
  <div class="inner circle shapeborder">
    <span>Iteration planning</span>
    <div class="inner circle shapeborder">
      <span>Daily planning</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```